# How to get the attention values separately save in a file

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Suppose I have a audio feature with tensor size [32,128,150] and video feature tensor [32,64,15], were first dimension is batch size, second is sequence/timestamp and third one is the no of features.
I also have attention values of tensor size [32,1,150] (for video to audio)and [32,1,15](for audio to video).How can I get the audio and video features combined in one csv file and the corresponding attention values in another csv file. This should be saved in such a way that when I am accessing one feature value I should able to access the corresponding attention value.

I am in doubt of how this can be done since the size of audio, video and attention values are different size tensor.

Comment: Why do they need to be saved to a csv? You can use `torch.save` to save tensors.